# Storing encrypted data in iOS keychain

Tags: mobile, ios, keychain, mobile-app

In my Unity app in C# I am using a 3rd party script which allows me store and retrieve data using iOS keychain. The stored data is a private user generated key which is used to encrypt data before backing the file online (not iCloud).

I checked the script’s code and found that it uses a hardcoded key/salt to encrypt/decrypt the data before interacting with the keychain.

I decided to get rid of the 3rd party encryption as it seems useless being hardcoded.

My question - isn’t the whole purpose of the keychain to store passwords safely without needing additional encryption of the data?

If not, I guess a better option is to store the keychain decryption key on a server, download it when the app is opened, decrypt the keychain entry, get the user key, encrypt a new file, back it up…

Comment: A hardcoded salt is worse than useless, it's actively dangerous.